# file is not downloading via DownloadManager in Android

Tags: android, url, android-download-manager

Hi i want to download video file and below is my code

```
public void file_download(String uRl) {
      File direct = new File(Constant.FOLDER_PATH);
      try {
       uRl = "http://songs7.funmaza.in/videos/"
         + URLEncoder
           .encode("Issey Kehte Hain Hip Hop 720p - Yo Yo Honey Singh [Funmaza.com].wmv",
             "UTF-8");
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println("URL For Download == " + uRl);
      if (!direct.exists()) {
       direct.mkdirs();
      }
      DownloadManager mdDownloadManager = (DownloadManager) ((Activity) context)
        .getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
      DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
        Uri.parse(uRl));
      request.setDescription("Downloading via Your app name..");
      request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
      request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(direct));
      mdDownloadManager.enqueue(request);

     }
```

and in download manager I got following information

[image]

If i pass simple URL like "http://beta-vidizmo.com/hilton.mp4" then it is working fine

Comment: What is the value of Constant.FOLDER_PATH ?

Comment: @Haresh that is Environment
   .getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyTest"

Comment: I think might be issue in your video path becz i try to change this path with some other image path and it working perfectly.

Comment: @Haresh http://songs7.funmaza.in/videos/Issey%20Kehte%20Hain%20Hip%20Hop%20720p%20-%20Yo%20Yo%20Honey%20Singh%20[Funmaza.com].wmv links perfectly working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Try and error, I found this solution,

```
    File direct = new File(Constant.FOLDER_PATH);
      uRl = "http://songs7.funmaza.in/videos/Issey Kehte Hain Hip Hop 720p - Yo Yo Honey Singh [Funmaza.com].wmv";
      uRl = uRl.replace(" ", "%20");
      uRl = uRl.replace("[", "%5B");
      uRl = uRl.replace("]", "%5D");
      System.out.println("URL For Download == " + uRl);
      if (!direct.exists()) {
       direct.mkdirs();
      }
      DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) ((Activity) context)
        .getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
      DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
        Uri.parse(uRl));
      request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
        DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
          | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
        .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
        .setDescription("Downloading via Your app name..")
        .setTitle("Issey Kehte Hain Hip Hop")
        .setNotificationVisibility(
          DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/MoviesAndSongs",
          "test1.mp4");
      downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

It's done :) Thanks Haresh to you also

Answer (score 4):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
file_download("http://songs7.funmaza.in/videos/Issey Kehte Hain Hip Hop 720p - Yo Yo Honey Singh [Funmaza.com].wmv",context);

public void file_download(String url,Context context) {
        url = url.replace(" ","%20");
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) ((Activity) context).getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                .setTitle("Demo")
                .setDescription("Downloading via Your app name..")
                .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder", "test1.3gp");
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);

    }
```

Comment: i run this code it working perfectly can you please try at least one time ?

Comment: Still it's showing me that Download Unsuccessfull :(

Comment: change this by this setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("MyFolder", "test1.3gp");

Comment: I have also changed but still it's giving me an message of Unsuccessfull:(

Comment: have you given this WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in AndroidManifest.xml ?